# Module not found Ant & Java9 Modularity

Tags: java, ant, java-module

Running into an issue migrating to Java modules using Ant. Ant/Java isn't picking up my log4j-1.2-api jar/module.

```
 error: module not found: org.apache.log4j
 requires org.apache.log4j;
```

Here is my module-info.java

```
module Core {
    requires java.xml;
    requires org.apache.log4j;
}
```

Here is how eclipse handles the module in .classpath

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/log4j-api-2.17.2.jar">
     <attributes>
        <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

And just to clarify, I had no issues prior to migrating from Java 8 to a newer version requiring modules. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue revolved around the build file trying to add a classpath instead of a modulepath.
**Before:**

```
<javac srcdir="@{dir}" destdir="${build.home}/classes/@{dir}" debug="true" release="17" includeantruntime="false" nowarn="${javac.nowarn}">
    <classpath refid="class.path" />
</javac>
```

**After**

```
<javac srcdir="@{dir}" destdir="${build.home}/classes/@{dir}" debug="true" release="17" includeantruntime="false" nowarn="${javac.nowarn}">
    <modulepath refid="class.path" />
</javac>
```

**classs.path** for extra context

```
<path id="class.path">
    <pathelement path="${build.home}/classes/src"/>
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```